# How to create a script which allows to track changes in the cell and and send me a message

Tags: google-apps-script

I get data from another document using the script:

```
 function importFunction1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AnFTFDi5xS7qdEg1bXF1SmFqMF9WZ0Z2RmpfOXZEU3c");
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("0AnFTFDi5xS7qdHUxTEVpTHp4MWxwZV9reUdxUVlRX2c");
  var targetSheet = ss2.getSheets()[0];
  var values = sourceSheet.setActiveSelection("A2:G100").getValues();
  targetSheet.setActiveSelection("A1:G99").setValues(values);
}
```

The data is inserted into the specified range. In another column I have a formula which shows that in the inserted row is the desired value.

Question: when a new row apeared with a script mentioned above. It is checked for relevant data and if there is, it sends me a message. How send myself a massage?

Thanks

Comment: it is not very clear what is the actual condition you want to check ... is it a difference in total row count ? or a specific content somewhere ? please be more acurate on this part to get a more acurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[`MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail)

It can email anyone anything, and you can use an optional fourth argument to specify other options.